# Proving a limit as n tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis

prove that $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n] n = 1 $$

I am unable to get a way to solve this, but I have done a question like the one below

prove that $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n] a = 1 $$

some one help me

Comment: If you suppose the limit, $L$, exists then $\log L =\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {\log n}n$.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the binomial formula: put $$x_n := n^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1 \geqq 0 \hspace{1.0cm} (n=1,2,3,...).$$ Thus, $n\geqq 2$ implies $$n = (x_n +1)^n = \sum_{j=0}^n {n\choose j} x_n^j \geqq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x_n^2.$$ Therefore, $$ 0 < x_n \leqq \sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}} \hspace{1.0cm} (n \geqq 2).$$ Letting $n \rightarrow \infty$, it follows that $x_n \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that: 
$$\sqrt[n] n =n^\frac{1}{n}=e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}$$
thus:
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt[n] n=\lim_{n\to+\infty}n^\frac{1}{n}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}=1
$$
since 
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n}=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the expression using e. This then reduces to showing that log(n)/n tends to 0 as n tends to infinity. which follows from l'Hôpital.

Comment: Which is a basic asymptotic result, I'd say…

Comment: And the limit in question is a basic limit. It's hard to know how much proof is required.

Comment: There are two kings of results: results that every has been taught, and results everyone has done as an exercise for its own sake ;o)